# Junit expected annotation fails for mvn and java 1.8

Tags: mockito, junit4, powermock

I have some negative test cases in which I am trying to test an exception for certain negative use cases.
JUnits are getting passed when running on eclipse, but when using mvn clean install, I am getting exception saying @Expected exception is not same as is getting thrown from the code.

We are seeing the failures for Java1.8

Code looks like below

```
@Test(expected=SomeException.class)
public void testTrust()
throws Exception
{
abc.trust(value1, value2)
}

class Abc{

protected void trust(string value1, string value2)throws exception1, exception2
{
//Some Logic

}
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the full error and stacktrace of the error that happens when you test the code with maven? It sounds like an exception other than the expected "SomeException" is thrown. Looking at the signature of Abc.trust, this method can atleast throw two different checked exceptions, you need to expect the right one in your test case

Answer (score 1):

The symptom would suggest that when you run the tests during the maven build there is **another Exception that is thrown before the one that you expected**. Maybe this can lead you to the solution?

But for a more helpful answer you have to provide more information like the StackTrace.